# Openstack juju yaml field explanations

Tags: openstack, juju

Can someone explain the meaning of the following key-value pairs in the following text?(or share the link that explains this. I went through the link http://pythonhosted.org/juju-deployer/config.html#placement but have difficulty in understanding it). It is part of the yaml bundle for deploying openstack.

keystone:

annotations:

```
    gui-x: '500'

    gui-y: '0'
```

charm:

```
    cs:trusty/keystone-31

    num_units: 1
```

options:

```
    admin-password: openstack

    ha-mcastport: 5403

    openstack-origin: cloud:trusty-liberty
```

to:

- lxc:3

Answer (score 1):

Although, this question is pretty old but let me explain a few things that I have little understanding about.

**Annotations** define where the service is placed on juju-gui (where juju gui is a graphical representation of services which you access from browser)

**cs:trusty/keystone-31** is a charm URL format for a juju controller which specifies that keystone charm version 33 of trusty series should be fetched from juju charms store. Juju controller controls the deployment of services/charms.

**num_units: 1** define the number of charm units to deploy

**options** are configuration parameters of a service (charm). Each charm has the configuration parameters defined in config.yaml file

**to** option defines where to deploy the service. In your example, **lxc:3** specifies that the service should be deployed on Machine No. 3 in an LXC. It is to be noted that Juju 2.0 has replaced LXC provider with LXD, so services are now deployed in LXDs.